# Focus the window of an already open document

Tags: gnome, evince

Switching from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, I noticed some regressive behaviour trying to re-open (e.g., in evince) a file already open. For example, suppose I open "foo.pdf". I now tab away to another program. Then I try to open "foo.pdf" from the launcher (or the terminal, via e.g., xdg-open). The expected behaviour (which used to work in 20.04) is that the evince window with "foo.pdf" is brought into focus. This is no longer the case in 22.04 or 22.10

Is this a bug or some intentional new "feature"? Is there some way to bring back the desired behaviour?

Comment: If you think this is a bug you can report it on this site. https://ubuntu.com/blog/the-keys-to-successful-bug-reporting

Answer (score 1):

This is an intentional feature of Gnome Shell, which you can remedy with an extension, such as [NoAnnoyance v2](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2182/noannoyance/) by bjoerndaase or [Window Is Ready - Notification Remover](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1007/window-is-ready-notification-remover/) by nunofarruca. Some extensions with a wider scope, such as [Unite](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/) by hardpixel and [Just Perfection](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/) by JustPerfection also include this as one of the options.